# domReady vs ready - Migrating to Polymer 1.0

Tags: polymer

In Polymer0.5, I had the following code:

Template:

```
<div class="scroll">
    <div class="content">
        <content></content>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
domReady: function() {
    var width = $(this.shadowRoot).find('.content')[0].scrollWidth;
}
```

This code worked, and I received a non-zero value for the width.

---

Now I am trying to migrate to Polymer1.0, I added an ID to the div:

```
<div class="scroll">
    <div id="content" class="content">
        <content></content>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the script is now:

```
ready: function() {
    var width = this.$.content.scrollWidth;
}
```

However, this width is `0`.

---

Is there a difference between the old `domReady` function, and the new `ready` function?  I have also tried using the `attached` function but it did not work either.

*When I try to access the `width` later on (triggered by a button press), then I get the non-zero value I am looking for.*

---

The element is used like this:

```
<my-scrollbar>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam purus leo, sagittis lobortis velit vel, viverra vulputate purus. Proin lacinia magna eu erat iaculis, eget mollis lectus mattis. 
</my-scrollbar>
```

So that inner text is what determines the dimensions of the element.

Comment: `this.$.<element>` automatic node finding only works on IDs, not classes.  Is that a typo in your template?

Comment: Sorry, I have added an `ID` to that element because I wasn't sure if the classes were the problem.  I will edit that in.

Comment: Since `this.$.content` is already referencing the node you should be able to get away with `this.$.content.scrollWidth`.  I don't think that'll solve your issue, but could save you some typing in the future.

Comment: I just reviewed the documentation for `async` and it says that if `async` is called with no wait time then it is executed with "microtask timing", which in Polymer's definition is before the next event/paint. Try wrapping the width check with `Polymer.async(function(){...},1)` to force it to wait until the paint completes.

Comment: I have just tested my code (not your async suggestion) in Safari, and it works fine there (but not in Chrome).  I will try with `async` to see if that fixes it for me in Chrome.

Comment: Also move it into `attached` to ensure it is executed after the component is attached to the DOM.  It may work in `ready`, but that may lead to race conditions with `async`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that my original code was working in Safari, but not in Chrome.

With [Zikes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/659590/zikes) suggestion, I added in some async, and now it works in both browsers.

Final answer:

```
attached: function() {
    this.async(function(){
        var width = this.$.content.scrollWidth;
    },1)
}
```

Comment: Glad that worked! Be sure to "accept" this answer since it solves the problem.

Comment: Yepp, can't except my own solution for a few days though.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to "flush" the DOM before working with it. In this case, the code would be:

```
attached: function() {
  var width;
  Polymer.dom.flush();
  width = this.$.content.scrollWidth;
},
```

Since this is synchronous, declarative, and doesn't involve closures, it could be easier to work with.

More information: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#dom-api